# How to generate a mark sheet with names from an array and display with textbox beside?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, html-table

I am trying to create a mark sheet for a project am currently working on where i have an array of names such as

```
var names = ["n1","n2","n3","n4","n5","n6","n7","n8"];
```

and i want to display the names in a table column and generate an amount of text boxes which is defined in a loop but so far i am having trouble to display the text boxes side by side of the names.

```
    html+= "<table>";
    html+= "<table style='border:1px solid black;'><tr><th>Student Name</th><th>ICA's</th>";
    for(var i = 0; i<=names.length;i++)//retrieve names from the array
    {
        for(var j=1;j<=2;j++)//amount of textboxes need to be created
        {
            html+= ("<tr><td id='tableTD'>"+names[i]+"</td><td>"+txtBox+"</td></tr></table>");
        }
    }
    display.innerHTML = html;
}
```

the result from this segment of codes is that i get a duplicate of the names with textbox beside them but not all in 1row for example "n1: textbox1, textbox2"

i have to display all that in a tables and i am limited to only html and javascript no jquery of server side language.

I cant seem to understand where the problem come from..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this more like what you're trying to do?

```
html = "<table>";
html+= "<tr><th>Student Name</th><th>ICA-1/th><th>ICA-2</th><th>Total</th></tr>";
for(var i = 0; i<=names.length;i++)//retrieve names from the array
{
    html += "<tr id='row" + i +"'><td>"+names[i]+"</td>";

    for(var j=1;j<=2;j++)//amount of textboxes need to be created
    {
        html+= "<td>"+txtBox+"</td>";
    }
    html += "<td id='total" + i "'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
}
html += "</table>";
display.innerHTML = html;
```

additional code based on further questions below:  (additional edits above and below to add totals to each row)

```
for (let row=0; row<names.length; row++) 
{ 
    let txtValue=document.querySelectorAll("#row" + row + " .stdMrk");
    if(txtValue.length>0)
    {
        let rowTotal = 0;
        for(var i = 0;i<=y;i++)
        {
            rowTotal += parseInt(txtValue[i].value);

        }
        //alert(rowTotal);
        document.querySelector("#total" + row).innerHTML = rowTotal;
    }

}
```

This outer loop gets the inputs for each row, then uses your loop to add them.

Comment: yes..this was precisely what i was looking for..judging by your ans, my error was that i was trying to generate everything within the 2nd loop which explain the duplication..
Thank you...

Comment: i am getting an extra rows at the bottom displaying undefined with the textboxes, any idea why this might be the case??

Comment: the loop should be i=0;i<names.length;i++.  The <= is stepping one too far.

Comment: hi..am sry to bother you again with this but am facing another issue where now i have to add all the values from the txt boxes which are generated by the for loop. I have tried for each but its only getting undefined and the value cant be retrieved from the txt boxes to be able to compute later on..
Thank you in advance..

Comment: Please add your current code to the post.  I suspect you need to add an id that includes your counter so that you can uniquely reference each input.

Comment: ..ive uploaded the codes below and also edited some of it to the updated version..

Answer (score 0):

@Noah B
The below codes is the ans i got from you to display the tables which ive modified it abit to acomodate my requirements.

```
for(var i = 0; i<names.length;i++)//retrieve names from the array
    {
        html += "<tr id='row" + i +"'><td style='border:1px solid black;'>"+names[i]+"</td>";
        for(var j=1;j<=2;j++)//amount of textboxes need to be created
        {
            html+= "<td style='border:1px solid black;'><input type='text' class='stdMrk' placeholder='0' value='0' /></td>";

        }
        for(var k=1;k<=1;k++)//display project or final exams txt box
        {
            html+= "<td style='border:1px solid black;'><input type='text' class='stdMrk' placeholder='0' value='0' /></td>";

        }
        html += "</tr>";
    }
```

But my other issue is that now i need to retrieve the value of each rows and from what you can see,ive added an additional for loop to display another set of textboxes which has the same class name as the previous one.

For example n1 will have 3int value entered from the keyboard and i have to compute that 3value and return it. It must be a loop which get repeated for each names.

This is the codes i've written to retrieve the value but it display all the value 1by 1 without any means to know from which rows this belong to..

```
var txtValue = document.getElementsByClassName("stdMrk");
if(txtValue.length>0)
{
    for(var i = 0;i<=y;i++)
    {
        x += parseInt(txtValue[i].value);

    }
    alert(x);
}//edit ive manage to create this but still need to iterate through all the names...
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: for (let row=0; row<names.length; row++) 
{ 
    let txtValue=document.querySelectorAll("#row" + row + " .stdMrk"); 
    [ . . . if / loop block . . . ]  
}

Comment: can i have a full code to understand because i can't seem to figure out what you are trying to say..

Comment: I added to my answer above.

Comment: @NoahB What this code is doing is just adding all the numbers according to the rows but what i was trying to acccomplished is to add the values and display the total for each rows..
for example row 1 has a total value of 3,row 2 has a total value of 5,row 3 total is 10..
each row having its own total value to be displayed with the array of names..

Comment: I added code to display the total on each row.  If I were doing this from scratch, I'd add an oninput handler to each text box to update the totals as the user entered data.